# How to output a Bootstrap button with glyphicon in CakePHP 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, glyphicons

I need to output a button with a glyphicon like this with CakePHP 3.
[image: native_code_button]

But I have managed to get till this [image: cakephp3_generated_button]

By using the following code.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('User',['controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'index'],['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'role' => 'button']);?>
```

I still need to include the below code to display the glyphicon

```
<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```

So how to include this in place of 'User' in the button title?

P.S. I don't want to use Bootstrap Helper Plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out myself.
This worked for me

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('span','',['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user']).' User',['controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'index'],['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'role' => 'button' , 'escape' => false]);?>
```

Comment: All too often, people come up with extremely hackish solutions which just happen to work. In this case, you've done exactly the right thing.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks Greg

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> user',['controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'],['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'role' => 'button', 'escape' => false]);?>
```

This may be a hack as it is not found in the Doc but it works well.

Comment: This is basically my answer but i am generating the '<span>' tag and you are not.